# Laravel 5 and way/generators

Tags: php, laravel, way-generators

I try to include `way/generators` to **laravel 5.0**

I follow these steps:

1. I include it into `require dev: require way/generators --dev`

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1,
    "way/generators" : "~3.0"
},
```

2. I do `composer update`, also I try with `composer update --dev`
3. I add a new item to the providers array.

```
'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

4. now when I type: `php artisan` in console I got error

   > exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method [package]' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testni\storage\framework\compiled.php:4351
   >   Stack trace:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the GitHub [`readme.md`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators/blob/master/readme.md) for [`JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators):

> There is no support for Laravel 5, as the framework now includes a
>   number of generators out of the box.

Comment: You could try using the package for Laravel 5
https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Answer (score 5):

For Laravel 5 Jeffrey Way already created Laravel 5 Extended Generators.

https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

You can even see it in action in Laracasts website.

https://laracasts.com/lessons/faster-workflow-with-generators

It is still using php artisan command but so far there are 3 additional methods like

- mmake:migration:schema
- make:migration:pivot
- make:seed

To install - composer require laracasts/generators --dev

Answer (score 1):

Generators included in laravel 5 are very useful now so maybe you shouldn't worry about that, just type in `php artisan` to see the full list of them, they are under the make section

Answer (score -1):

`composer require laracasts/generators --dev`

---

Add this to config/app.php

---

`'Laracasts\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',`